# Sci fi show about a boy with powers with rays coming out of a prism

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi

I watched this show when I sass a kid (80-90s) about a boy that has some kind of powers. It’s set in the UK I think, in a cabin/lodge. It has a spooky theme where you see a prism slowly making taking position as the center piece. I think it has the ray of light hitting it and it goes through the prism and out comes more rays. And I think you can see the boys face as the prism becomes hes third eye at his forehead. And the main color is greenish I think. The episodes is about the boy, maybe 10 years old. He is been taking care of by a woman I believe. And not every episode was something sci fi in it. I think the series was about the boy trying to figure out his powers.

Comment: Are you sure that it was a show (a series) and not a film? It sounds a lot like Jim Henson's [The Dark Crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Crystal).

Comment: no sorry. i have seen the dark crystal. love the movie. they are making a new series of it on netflix btw =)

Comment: Both accepted in comments, but both accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess that the show you are looking for is called Chocky. It is a British children's TV adaptation of the John Wyndham novel. The time frame you suggests fits accurately as does the the description of the opening theme. You can see the theme (and probably some episodes) on You Tube. Here is a link to the opening.